# regex for string followed by anything and stopping at |

Tags: regex, parsing, grep

I am using grep to parse a log file for URLs. The file is delimited by the pipe character `|`.

I would like to use grep to extract all of the URLs that match a certain string. The catch is, I want the entire URL field. So far I have the following regex:

```
grep -oE 'URL\=.*ZJRWYZFTY.*\|' filename
```

However, it grabs everything after the ZJRWYZFTY string, including the other fields. Is there a way to capture everything in the URL feild that matches the ZJRWYZFTY string up to the | ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` will do a greedy match for `.*`, so it captures everything. You can do `[^|]*` instead of `.*` to make it behave like you want. `[^|]` will match all characters other than `|`:

`grep -oE 'url\=[^|]*ZJRWYZFTY[^|]*' filename`

But it seems `awk` is the more suitable tool here. Assuming the url field is the second field, you can do:

`awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /ZJRWYZFTY/ {print $2}" filename`

Comment: Thanks! Your grep command did the trick. I would use AWK, however these logs have ~100 fields, and the URL field is not always the same number, which is why I wanted to use a regex to find it.